# Ag Grid's flush update problem when changing browser tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using ag-grid v23 for stock board and updating data at high frequency about ~100 ms/message.
I'm using `batchUpdateRowData` to update multiple row.
The board updates normally when I focus on its tab, but when I change to others tab and after a while back to board tab, It starts to flush all updated data which receives from the moment I'm not on board tab until when I come back, It makes a very terrible performance. Any idea how this happens and how to resolve this? I tried to upgrade to ag-grid v25 but the problem still there.

Answer (score 1):

When you change tabs, the current focused Grid in the tab is destroyed so any data update, filter, sort changes is not saved unless you save it yourself e.g. to a store. When you go back to the tab, the Grid is created and initialised with the data provided.

You may find this blog post useful as it shows how you can persist and restore state with AG Grid, React & Redux: https://blog.ag-grid.com/persisting-ag-grid-state-with-react-redux/

I would recommend binding your data to a store, and leverage one of the following Grid Events to listen to whenever you are updating the data to then save it to a store:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous

`rowDataChanged` - The client has set new data into the grid using api.setRowData() or by changing the rowData bound property.

`rowDataUpdated` - The client has updated data for the grid using api.applyTransaction(transaction) or by changing the rowData bound property with immutableData=true.

`componentStateChanged` - Only used by React, Angular and VueJS AG Grid components (not used if doing plain JavaScript or Angular 1.x). If the grid receives changes due to bound properties, this event fires after the grid has finished processing the change.

Once you've saved your data to a store, you can then leverage the Grid Event `gridReady` or `firstDataRendered` to load the data inside the store whenever the grid is created.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the Browser's behavior. You might want to disable browser's throttling when you switch tab or catch the tab switch event and stop your updates until reactivate.